# Compilation error for Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, mpi, rdma

I am trying to build Tensorflow 1.6 with MPI support. I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: /gpfshome01/u/amalik/Tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/gdr/BUILD:52:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/contrib/gdr:gdr_memory_manager' failed (Exit 1)
>   tensorflow/contrib/gdr/gdr_memory_manager.cc:28:27: fatal error: rdma/rdma_cma.h: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>                              ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
>   Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 556.299s, Critical Path: 183.28s
>   FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

---

Any suggestion and comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on a RHEL7 like system

```
sudo yum install -y rdma-core-devel
```

and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libibverbs-dev
```

You need to have libibverbs-dev in your system.